# JavaScript to change Year displayed based on month/day

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script that if today's date is  before January 16, the current year will print, but if today's date is greater than or equal to January 16, the following year will print.

I am pretty new to coding JavaScript so perhaps I am just missing something stupid. Can anyone help by looking over this code and tell me what I did wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var dd = today.getday();
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

var today = new Date("mm/dd") 
var other = new Date("01/16")

if (today < other){
var printDate = theDate.getFullYear();  
}

else if (today >= other){
var printDate = theDate.getFullYear()+1;      
}
</script>
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<strong>16 January</strong> <script>document.write(printDate);</script>
```

Output right now is "undefined." Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot just compare dates like this `today < 01/16`,

Comment: @RedaMeskali Thank you. How can I correct the date comparison? (sorry newbie to Javascript)

Comment: Native Javascript give you very little options for comparing dates. Theoretically you could write your own library to handle this, but there's already a great one called moment.js; https://momentjs.com/

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38196054/6158118) answer please.

Comment: @RedaMeskali I changed my code above. It's still not working but I'm working on it.

Comment: please change today to be a Date object also today = mm/dd means division not concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date("mm/dd") // Invalid Date
var other = new Date("01/16") // Tue Jan 16 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

this should start you on the right process - you need to compare each calendar item (first month, then day) to determine what you are looking for

all the variables you need:

```
var Today_day = (integer)
var Today_month = (integer)
var Compare_day = (integer) 16 // or 15? not sure about base 0 for a day
var Compare_month = (integer) 0
```

you know how to get `Today_day` and `Today_month` - so you should have everything you need

Answer (score 1):

The simplified condition is: if month is not January (not 0), or date is after the 15th, then get next year:

```js
var today = new Date, year = today.getFullYear();  

if (today.getMonth() || today.getDate() > 15) year++;

console.log( year );
```

Or a bit shorter on one line:

```js
var date = new Date, year = date.getFullYear() + (date.getMonth() || date.getDate() > 15)

console.log( year );
```

Comment: Thanks fro this @Slai. So all that code I worked on can be replaced with this simple condition?

Comment: @beingbecoming yes, pretty much without the console.log

Comment: Thank you. This is brilliant coding. I've accepted your answer. Thanks again @Slai

Comment: I need to get more comfortable with console.log . It seems so useful.